# Deploy Cloud Function for Nuxt.js Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Is there any way to deploy cloud function which enable server side rendering for Nuxt in Firebase, since node used on Firebase is version 6.11.1 and minimal node version for Nuxt version 1 and up is 8. Every time I deploy the function, it get an error like this

[image: Deployment Error]

I also have added Babel configuration like this, but it still didn't worked.

```
babel: {
  'presets': [
    'es2015',
    'stage-0'
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['transform-runtime', {
      'polyfill': true,
      'regenerator': true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the related nuxt.js issue

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2714#issuecomment-393868687

`The latest build of nuxt-edge supports Node 6.x again by automatically falling back to the legacy build.`

Therefore a

```
npm install -S nuxt-edge babel-polyfill
```

should solve your problem now

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something ahead of the deploy to make sure your code is compiled and placed in the correct location for the Firebase CLI to find an deploy it.  This is going to be highly dependent on your own setup.  If you use the Firebase CLI to create a JavaScript project, it will want to deploy everything in your functions folder, and you'll need an index.js in there will your function definitions.  If you want to change the deployment folder, you can do that in `firebase.json` in the "functions" stanza.  Maybe also a [predeploy hook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#predeploy_and_postdeploy_hooks) will make this easier for you.

In my opinion, if you want advanced JavaScript language features such as async/await, it's far easier to [tell the CLI to create a TypeScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript).  It will automatically arrange to have the TypeScript compiled into JavaScript before deployment, so you don't have to do anything other than run the deploy command.